# Is it possible to add a key without a value in hashtable Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hashtable

I'm trying to work with Java's Junit Test. My goal is to create a hashtable as

```
Hashtable< String , Hashtable<String,String> > student = 
    new Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, String>>();
```

Next, I want to add at first only the key. After that, when I have the value then add it to the key in hashtable.

**Example**

```
student.put("student1",null) ;
```

I tried to work with null, but during test process I get a

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Is it not possible? Any ideas to how adding only the key without value?

Comment: Also, as a side note, `Hashtable` is a synchronized collection that has been outdated since Java 1.2. You should probably use a `HashMap` if you don't care about thread saftery, or a `ConcurrentHashMap` if you do.

Comment: Why would you *want* to add a key with no value? It would make more sense to check for the key and see that there was *no* value.

Comment: @Mureinik **no**!  Javadoc: "Any non-null object can be used as a key or as a value. ... Neither the key nor the value can be null. " -  Need a `HashMap` to accept `null`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yeah, just saw that now. Haven't actually used a `Hashtable` in almost two decades, so my memory of these caveats isn't great. I've removed my wrong comment.

Comment: Try `HashMap` or You can define a global object(maybe static field from some class) to stand for null, just a placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to add a key without a value in hashtable Java?

Short answer: No

Why?

Because it will throw and Exception if

```
 * @exception  NullPointerException  if the key or value is
 *               <code>null</code>
```

And in the same source code has a validation

```
 public synchronized V put(K key, V value) {
        // Make sure the value is not null
        if (value == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
...
```

You can use a Map Instead.

Answer (score 1):

HashTable is an older implementation and HashMap came as an advanced version with more capabilities. You can't call .equals() or .hashCode() on it as null isn't an object.

HashMap is a better replacement for single threaded applications or any time synchronization is not a requirement, because of the performance impact synchronization introduces. If you need a Threadsafe option you can also use ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: The OP isn't using `null` as a key, they're using `null` as a *value*. You don't need to call `equals` or `hashCode` on the value in a hash table/map.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put-K-V-) says that you can't:

> Maps the specified key to the specified value in this hashtable.
>   **Neither the key nor the value can be null.**

The best that you can do, if you need the key, is to use an empty `HashTable` as the value:

```
student.put("student1", new Hashtable<>());
```

Answer (score 0):

In most use cases you would not care about putting `null` into a HashMap. You can check which keys have a value assigned via the `keySet()` and treat everything else as `null` (since it was never assigned).

However, your question to me indicates that you need to distinguish three states: Key-Value pair, key that were never assigned a value, and keys that were *explicitly* assigned a `null` value.

Since the default `HashMap` does not support this behavior, you could implement your own class that implements the `Map` interface. It basically only wraps a `HashMap`, with a few important exceptions:

- When you assign a value of `null` to a key, you put the key into a `Set` of "NullKeys" instead of into the `HashMap`.
- When you retrieve a key, check whether it is in the "NullKey" `Set`. If yes, return `null`, otherwise look into the `HashMap`.

There are some special cases (overwriting an existing value with `null` etc.) but this would be the basic strategy.

(I am not sure whether this is a useful class to have other than in very specialized scenarios but it would meet your requirements.)